# Could you simplify the last part of following piece of news?

Tags: word-meaning

> "It was a very tough match today. I couldn't believe that I came from behind again. She played really well and she was fighting the whole match," said Halep.
>
> "I'm very excited that I can play in my biggest final tomorrow. I hope that I can control my emotions and just play.
>
> "I just have to enjoy it. I'm really happy that I can play the final here in Madrid."
>
> However, the 22-year-old is aware of the size of the task that awaits her in Sharapova having lost in **their only two meetings** to date.
>
> ([Source](http://www.afp.com/en/news/sharapova-faces-halep-madrid-open-final))

I am confused and cannot tell what the "having lost in their only two meetings" here means.

But please, do not define the whole phrase, break it down.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'meeting' in your highlighted sentence, taken in context, means a tennis match. It conveys that Halep has previously played against Sharapova twice, and lost on both occasions. As a result, she is aware that defeating Sharapova in the next game will not be easy.